# Confused with the excepted behavior of boost::locale regarding the capitalization of "ß"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-locale

I am trying to use the `boost::locale` library to perform uppercase and lowercase conversion of strings in my code (version 1.71).

I have an issue with the capitalization of "ß". In order to be compliant with already existing unit tests in my codebase, I want the letter "ß" to be capitalized to "SS". This should not be an issue, since this is the expected behavior as far as I understand (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions.html).

Here is a copy of the example provided on this page for reference:

> `Upper GRÜSSEN`
>
> `Lower grüßen`
>
> `Title Grüßen`
>
> `Fold  grüssen`

However, this is not the case when I use the method in my code. The "ß" stays as "ß" when applying the uppercase method.

I was confused and found the following example in the `boost::locale` library source:

```
//
//  Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Artyom Beilis (Tonkikh)
//
//  Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See
//  accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
//  http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <ctime>



int main()
{
    using namespace boost::locale;
    using namespace std;
    // Create system default locale
    generator gen;
    locale loc=gen(""); 
    locale::global(loc); 
    cout.imbue(loc);

    
    cout<<"Correct case conversion can't be done by simple, character by character conversion"<<endl;
    cout<<"because case conversion is context sensitive and not 1-to-1 conversion"<<endl;
    cout<<"For example:"<<endl;
    cout<<"   German grüßen correctly converted to "<<to_upper("grüßen")<<", instead of incorrect "
                    <<boost::to_upper_copy(std::string("grüßen"))<<endl;
    cout<<"     where ß is replaced with SS"<<endl;
    cout<<"   Greek ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ is correctly converted to "<<to_lower("ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ")<<", instead of incorrect "
                    <<boost::to_lower_copy(std::string("ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ"))<<endl;
    cout<<"     where Σ is converted to σ or to ς, according to position in the word"<<endl;
    cout<<"Such type of conversion just can't be done using std::toupper that work on character base, also std::toupper is "<<endl;
    cout<<"not even applicable when working with variable character length like in UTF-8 or UTF-16 limiting the correct "<<endl;
    cout<<"behavior to unicode subset BMP or ASCII only"<<endl;
   
}

// vim: tabstop=4 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4

// boostinspect:noascii
```

I tried compiling it, and this is the result I get:

```
Correct case conversion can't be done by simple, character by character conversion
because case conversion is context sensitive and not 1-to-1 conversion
For example:
   German grüßen correctly converted to GRÜßEN, instead of incorrect GRüßEN
     where ß is replaced with SS
   Greek ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ is correctly converted to ὀδυσσεύσ, instead of incorrect ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ
     where Σ is converted to σ or to ς, according to position in the word
Such type of conversion just can't be done using std::toupper that work on character base, also std::toupper is 
not even applicable when working with variable character length like in UTF-8 or UTF-16 limiting the correct 
behavior to unicode subset BMP or ASCII only
```

Emphasis on the part:

```
   German grüßen correctly converted to GRÜßEN, instead of incorrect GRüßEN
     where ß is replaced with SS
```

I really don't get what is going on in this sentence. What is the actual expected behavior?

Comment: Note, since Unicode version 5.1 (2008) one can use a [Capital ẞ (U+1E9E ẞ LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E).

Comment: If the example is broken, this should be reported as a Boost.Locale issue, no?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Question appears to be essentially: Is the example broken?

Comment: Assuming you copy-pasted the output of the example without modification, these are indeed all small letter sharp S, not the capital versions. That doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: @eerorika Isn't it broken by definition? It literally disagrees with itself! + OP already quoted the expected behaviour from the documentation....

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Thus an implied variation of the question is: Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: @eerorika Heh yep and I think that line of questioning belongs in a Boost.Locale issue report tbh

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I opened an issue here: https://github.com/boostorg/locale/issues/51

Comment: The example code uses the system locale. If you set your system locale to, say, `en_US` it will convert `grüßen` to `GREN`, which is fine since `ü` and `ß` do not exist in ASCII. The example runs correctly for me when I set my locale to `de_DE.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has been updated in the following commit: https://github.com/Flamefire/locale/commit/bae1f380ad0719121dfe048c56119bf72e074144

It now reads:

> German grüßen would be incorrectly converted to GRÜßEN, while
> Boost.Locale converts it to GRÜSSEN where ß is replaced with SS.

So the expected behavior is indeed to capitalize "ß" as "SS".

I assume this wasn't the case in my code because I didn't compile boost.locale with the ICU backend. I no longer have access to the original code, so I can't confirm this theory.